# what is this site NOT for? (to answer questions concerning elementary music theory? chords?)

Tags: discussion

... questions that could be answered by consulting wikipedia or youtube, elementary courses of music etc?

In another group I have found this restriction for put on hold:
**"This site is about the usage and rules of the German language. It is not well-suited to replace a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table. If you have already consulted such sources and still have questions, please edit your question to explain what you found and why it did not help. See this post on Meta for more information."**

I think there should be a similar "warning" that prevents for asking questions that could easily be answered by consulting first wiki, or a side link with basic information to music theory as: the name of the notes, staffs, clefs, scales, chords, circle of fifths and elements of rhythm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this site is not for is mostly explained in the *it is not about...* section at https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. I won't quote it here as it is subject to change.

There isn't any overall 'low bar' to clear when it comes to the level of question, and though I could see the logic in not allowing questions that could be answered simply by consulting a well-known resource, I don't recall that being a common problem with beginner-level questions asked here.

Comment: When I at first sometimes  almost got upset by some real elementary questions I  have meanwhile learnt that I profit a lot by answering questions of a very low level: understanding English terminolgy of music, trying to express myself in a foreign language, exchange opinions, understand how SE functions and even how the Ipad of my is working (a lot of new funtions I did‘t know before, also some ideas of hypertext markup lanuage. I‘ve understood that my new beeing in SE is not much different than the elementary questions of a beginner in music. My respect  of the friendly tone in here. chapeau!

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli I totally agree - I think SE probably functions best when we take the opportunity to practice our communication skills as well as share our knowledge of the site topic!

Comment: answers accepted, both very similar. is there no possibility to give the accept at each one?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Unfortunately not - sometimes it would seem useful, but IMHO it's not always useful to 'accept' answers on more opinion-based questions (which those found on meta often are), as the balance of upvotes and downvotes might be more useful to other readers.

Comment: I guess sometimes some of the very elementary questions are the ones that are hardest to find the exact answers to by searching, since they're assumed, like [this one](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/118586/in-sheet-music-can-notes-of-a-chord-have-different-length-or-how-to-read-this) which boils down to "When two note-dots are on one stem, does the eighth-note flag make them both eighth notes?"

Answer (score 3):

While advising users to refrain from basic, unresearched questions is a principle of this site, I believe that a side link with basic music theory information is not a good idea. I believe that function is already filled by linking questions that provide great information to these questions as reference.

Comment: Well, would it be appropriate then to give some standard answers or post ever  same links or tutorials to quite different questions? (as the one who asks won‘t always see the relationship to an other question by the hint: this has already been asked ...)

Comment: If it's directly mentioned to them? The hope is that they'll learn the stuff they need to know through the link in other's answers/comments. It'd be okay to do that, I just don't think we need the side link in the question-forming page.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli to some extent, our practice of closing questions as duplicates (where an existing question has an answer) should lead to some "standard answers" emerging over time.

Comment: yes, topo morto, that's a good point! then it will be also appropriate to give similar answers and post same links to different questions that lack of the same ressources?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli It shouldn't be necessary to post similar answers - instead, we have a process to close a question as duplicate - [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48487/how-to-find-the-key-from-chords) is an example. Users with over 3000 'rep' can vote to close, although any user can help by finding duplicates. https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges shows the various actions different levels of user can take.